# When is TeXLive's next release date? (and where is this information published?)

Tags: texlive

According to [TeXLive's homepage](https://www.tug.org/texlive/), the current release is TeX Live 2016, and it is implied that the next release will be called 'TeX Live 2017' (the page states "Plans for TeX Live 2017").

When is TeX Live 2017's expected release date?

The TeXLive homepage claims June 1st, but clearly this was not the case, as today is June 2nd.

Comment: The official homepage is https://www.tug.org/texlive/ . There it says 1st June is the planned date.  But last year the actual release was the 5th June.  If you look at the mailing list archives linked to from that page, you will see it is close to release, so expect it any day soon.

Comment: Also waiting for the new release. Don't want to download 3GB and write tens of thousands of files on my system twice within a matter of a few days

Comment: @AndrewSwann an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really can't wait any longer, simply install `TeXLive2017 pretest`!

I have written an [blog article](http://www.kleberj.de/2017/04/ein-texlive-mirror-pretest-auf-einem-synology-nas/) (in german ;-)) how to run a TeXLive mirror on a NAS in your LAN, but the basic steps are the same.

Download the distribution .e.g. with

`rsync -av --delete --exclude="mactex*" ftp.cstug.cz::pub/tex/local/tlpretest /path/to/dir`

or just the `installer` for a network installation and then run the relevant installer for your OS, e.g.:

`install-tl-windows -repository http://<NAS-IP>/tlpretest -gui wizard` or

`install-tl-windows -repository http://<TL2017pretest-URL> -gui wizard` or

`install-tl-windows -repository /path/to/dir -gui wizard`

See also: [Pretesting TeX Live](https://www.tug.org/texlive/pretest.html)

Wait for a while or even a bit longer! ;-)

```
$ latex -v
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX)
kpathsea version 6.2.3
Copyright 2017 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.29; using libpng 1.6.29
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 3.04
```

There won't be any changes, so this pretest version will be the official release version of TeXLive 2017!

As soon as TL2017 is officially released simply change the default repository back to its default or a server of your preference:

`tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet`

No need to wait for the official release! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

TeX Live 2017 was released today. Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks. Have you any idea how long it should take the MacTeX distribution to follow suit?

Comment: Should be there already, both are released at the same time

Comment: It's not there yet.

Comment: Mirrors need time to sync several GB, please wait or check different mirrors.